# My For() loop doesn't complete all element JS

Tags: javascript, for-loop

```
[
    { 
        task : { id : 1,    id_parent : "",     , is_parent : true      } 
    },
    { 
        task : { id : 2,    id_parent : "",     , is_parent : true      } 
    },
    { 
        task : { id : 3,    id_parent : "1",    , is_parent : false     } 
    },
    { 
        task : { id : 4,    id_parent : "2",    , is_parent : false     } 
    },
    { 
        task : { id : 5,    id_parent : "1",    , is_parent : false     } 
    },
    { 
        task : { id : 6,    id_parent : "1",    , is_parent : true      } 
    },
    { 
        task : { id : 7,    id_parent : "2",    , is_parent : false     } 
    },
    { 
        task : { id : 8,    id_parent : "2",    , is_parent : true      } 
    },
    { 
        task : { id : 9,    id_parent : "1",    , is_parent : true      } 
    },
    { 
        task : { id : 10, id_parent : "9",  , is_parent : false     } 
    },
    { 
        task : { id : 11, id_parent : "9",  , is_parent : false     } 
    },
    { 
        task : { id : 12, id_parent : "8",  , is_parent : true      } 
    },
    { 
        task : { id : 13, id_parent : "2",  , is_parent : false     } 
    },
    { 
        task : { id : 14, id_parent : "6",  , is_parent : true      } 
    },
    { 
        task : { id : 15, id_parent : "12", , is_parent : true      } 
    },
    { 
        task : { id : 16, id_parent : "15",     , is_parent : false     } 
    },
    { 
        task : { id : 17, id_parent : "8",  , is_parent : false     } 
    },
    { 
        task : { id : 18, id_parent : "15",     , is_parent : false     } 
    }
]    
// return direct child of the id_task
    // where this direct child is a prent
    this.getDirectChildParent = function(id_task, array_tasks){
        var tasks = array_tasks;
        if (array_tasks === undefined) {
            tasks = this.getAllTasks();
        }
        var allChildParent = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < tasks.length; i++) {
            var task = tasks[i].task;
            if(task.is_parent && task.id_parent == id_task) allChildParent.push(task.id);
        }
        return allChildParent;
    }

    // return direct child of the id_task
    // where this direct child is not a prent
    this.getDirectNotParentChild = function(id_task, array_tasks){
        var tasks = array_tasks;
        if (array_tasks === undefined) {
            tasks = this.getAllTasks();
        }
        var allDirectChild = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < tasks.length; i++) {
            var task = tasks[i].task;
            if(!task.is_parent && task.id_parent == id_task) {
                allDirectChild.push(task.id);
                /*tasks.splice(i, 1);
                i--;*/
            }
        }
        return allDirectChild;
    }
this.getAllChilderenTask = function(id_task, array_tasks){
        var id_child = [];
        var tasks = array_tasks;

        if (array_tasks === undefined) {
            tasks = this.getAllTasks();
        }

        id_child = id_child.concat(this.getDirectNotParentChild (id_task, tasks));
        id_child_parent = this.getDirectChildParent (id_task, tasks);
        id_child = id_child.concat(id_child_parent);

        if(id_child_parent.length != 0){
            for (var i = 0; i < id_child_parent.length; i++) {
                id_child = id_child.concat( this.getAllChilderenTask (id_child_parent[i], tasks) );
            }
        }

        return id_child;
    }
```

Hello,
i'm trying to make a function that return to me an array of child.
My problem is when i use my function it works but it doesn't give me all child of my Chosen Task, for example when i do 
object.getAllChilderenTask(1)
 it return : 
Array [ 3, 5, 6, 9, 14 ]
But the correct one should be : [ 3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 11, 14 ].
I found the problem but i don't know how to fix it.

```
if(id_child_parent.length != 0){
            for (var i = 0; i < id_child_parent.length; i++) {
                id_child = id_child.concat( this.getAllChilderenTask (id_child_parent[i], tasks) );
            }
        }
```

It loops only for the first element (WTF).
if i remove id_child from the loop, it loops on all element, i'm using a recursive methode (getAllChilderenTask).

Do you have any idea ?

Comment: You should make a js fiddle to show your output and your expected output

Comment: you don't need to wrap your for loop in an if that checks the length. The middle clause of the for loop `i < ic_child_parent.length` already ensures the loop won't run if the length = 0. Use your developer tools to debug this (hit f12 to see the console).

Comment: #scrappedcola, really i forget that code their. thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Well guys,
my mistake was, that in my recursive methode i used a variable id_parent_child like a global one, so when my programme works foreach time it call the same methode this var changed.
The solution was to add , var id_child_parent = []; 
to be a local method variable.

```
    this.getAllChilderenTask = function(id_task, array_tasks){
            var id_child = [];
            var id_child_parent = [];
            var tasks = array_tasks;

            if (array_tasks === undefined) {
                tasks = this.getAllTasks();
            }

            id_child = id_child.concat(this.getDirectNotParentChild (id_task, tasks));
            id_child_parent = this.getDirectChildParent (id_task, tasks);
            id_child = id_child.concat(id_child_parent);

            if(id_child_parent.length != 0){
                for (var i = 0; i < id_child_parent.length; i++) {
                    id_child = id_child.concat( this.getAllChilderenTask (id_child_parent[i], tasks) );
                }
            }

            return id_child;
        }
```

That's all. :)